# Resolution independent cubic bezier drawing on GPU (Blinn/Loop)

Tags: gpu, resolution, bezier, cubic

Based on the following resources, I have been trying to get resolution independent cubic bezier rendering on the GPU to work:

[GPU Gems 3 Chapter 25](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html)

[Curvy Blues](http://www.mdk.org.pl/2007/10/27/curvy-blues)

[Resolution Independent Curve Rendering using Programmable Graphics Hardware](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/LoopBlinn05.pdf)

But as stated in the Curvy Blues website, there are errors in the documents on the other two websites. Curvy Blues tells me to look at the comments, but I don't seem to be able to find those comments. Another forum somewhere tells me the same, I don't remember what that forum was. But there is definitely something I am missing.

Anyway, I have tried to regenerate what is happening and I fail to understand the part where the discriminant is calculated from the determinants of a combination of transformed coordinates.

So I have the original coordinates, I stick them in a 4x4 matrix, transform this matrix with the M3-matrix and get the C-matrix.
Then I create 3x3 matrices from the coordinates in the C-matrix and calculate the determinants, which then can be combined to create the a, b and c of the quadratic equation that will help me find the roots.

Problem is, when I do it exactly like that: the discriminant is incorrect. I clearly put in coordinates for a serpentine (a symmetric one, but a correct serpentine), but it states it is a cusp.
When I calculate it myself using wxMaxima, deriving to 1st and 2nd order and then calculating the cross-product, simplifying to a quadratic equation, the discriminant of that equation seems to be correct when I put in the same coordinates.
When I force the code to use my own discriminant to determine if it's a serpentine or not, but I use the determinants to calculate the further k,l,m texture coordinates, the result is also incorrect.
So I presume there must be an error in the determinants.

Can anyone help me get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have managed to solve it. The results are near to perfect (sometimes inverted, but that's probably a different problem).

This is where I went wrong, and I hope I can help other people to not waste all the time I have wasted searching this.

I have based my code on the blinn-phong document.
I had coordinates b0, b1, b2, b3. I used to view them as 2D coordinates with a w, but I have changed this view, and this solved the problem. By viewing them as 3D coordinates with z = 0, and making them homogenous 4D coordinates for transformation (w = 1), the solution arrived.

By calculating the C matrix: C = M3 * B, I got these new coordinates.
When calculating the determinants d0, d1, d2, d3, I used to take the x, y coordinates from columns 0 and 1 in the C matrix, and the w factor from column 2. WRONG! When you think of it, the coordinates are actually 3D coordinates, so, for the w-factors, one should take column 3 and ignore column 2.

This gave me correct determinants, resulting in a discriminant that was able to sort out what type of curve I was handling.

But beware, what made my search even longer was the fact that I assumed that when it is visibly a serpentine, the result of the discriminant should always be > 0 (serpentine).
But this is not always the case, when you have a mathematically perfect sepentine (coordinates are so that the mean is exact middle), the determinant will say it's a cusp (determinant = 0). I used to think that this result was wrong, but it isn't. So don't be fooled by this.

Comment: great, I read your answer, It helped a lot. Do you know how to solve the artifact on Loop case? I have a question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970673/how-to-solve-rendering-artifact-in-blinn-loops-resolution-independent-curve-ren

Comment: No, sadly enough I had some unsolved issues and I stopped trying to fix it... But I see now that you just solved it in that thread, maybe your solution helps with my issues... I'll look into it!

Comment: I have one more issue actually, the rendered curves can be either convex or concave, I'm still wondering if there's a testing to determine this.

Comment: I actually believe I can help you with that: when det1 < 0 then flip the signs on all the k and l factors of the 4 resulting klm's, leaving the m factor unchanged. This has something to do with that the Hessian should be negative but my math is not good enough to understand what the Hessian is.

Comment: By the way: this sign-solution is only for serpentines (see documentation part about serpentines), I don't think you will have the convex/concave problem with other curve types.

Comment: Hi, I get a chance to revisit my project again, too bad before I wasn't aware about artifact on serpentine curve. can you describe more clearly in flipping the sign? I'm quite confused about that

Comment: I don't understand the theory behind it, but in practice this is what you should do: When you have figured out that you are drawing a 'serpentine' or 'cusp with inflection at infinity', after you have calculated the klm factors, test that if determinant1 < 0. When it is, flip the signs (negate them) on all the k and l factors. Do this before you untransform them.

Comment: I tried to detect this if(curveType == SERPENTINE && d1 < 0)
then flip (if previously k^3 - lm <= 0 it should becomes k^3 - lm > 0)
but it doesn't work. another strange thing is the problem also occurs when d1 > 0, I almost give up

Comment: Oh I also made a new question on here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70178/how-to-fix-problem-in-serpentine-case-using-blinn-loop-algorithm
perhaps you can take a look

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. You should not change your k^3-lm <= 0 equation. You should just have the GPU hardware interpolate between -k, -l and m factors, so you need to change the texture-coordinates that you are sending to the shader. And, even that's not really true, because the k, l and m factors need to be transformed back first, so they might not even be -k, -l, m after the transformation.

Comment: Thanks man, I think you're correct, I need to change k and l to -k and -l. Actually I almost gave up since checking d1 < 1 doesn't detect the artifact, but fortunately I got a really good source code here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298.39/platform/graphics/gpu/. It's much more stable now

Comment: Great link! I'll look into it as I also still have artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

The book GPU Gem 3 has a mistake here, and [the page on nVidia's website](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html) has the mistake too:

> ```
> a3 = b2 * (b1 x b1)
> ```

It's actually `a3 = b2 * (b1 x b0)`.

There're other problems about this algorithm: the exp part of the floating point will overflow during the calculation, so you should be cautious and add normalize operations into your code.

Comment: I have never found a perfectly working solution, so what you are saying might be it. Maybe I'll dig into this again someday, because resolution independent cubic beziers are cool...