# Classifying cubic bezier curves according to Loop & Blinn 2005

Tags: math, rust, graphics, 2d, bezier

I am trying flatten a bezier path (remove all intersections and replace with end points) as part of the implementation of the rendering algorithm described [here](https://arbook.icg.tugraz.at/schmalstieg/Schmalstieg_365.pdf) and found the algorithm described by Loop and Blinn in [GPU Gems 3 Ch. 25](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-25-rendering-vector-art-gpu), with correction for $a3$'s cross product to detect curve self-intersection (loops).

The algorithm calls for the evaluation of the expression `discr=d₁²(3d₂²-4d₁d₃)` such that the curve is self-intersecting iff the `discr < 0`.

where

`d₁=a₁-2a₂+3a₃`,
`d₂=-a₂+3a₃`,
`d₃=3a₃`

`a₁=b₀·(b₃⨯b₂)`,
`a₂=b₁·(b₀⨯b₃)`,
`a₃=b₂·(b₁⨯b₀)`

I have implemented the algorithm in the sample code below, as well as that of a few other algorithms I have been able to find. None of them agree, and all of them are wrong. Specifically, I have implemented

1. The algorithm described in GPU Gems 3
2. The same algorithm as described in the original paper.
3. The same algorithm as implemented in paper.js ([issue](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#canonical))([sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/zVltb9tGEv4rG3+oXiIxIuW0gFzXaN3kkA9tek1wH84xjBW5kgnTJEMuZTmp//s9M7sklyLtpAEKnADLy53ZmWdn522pz0epvFVHq6N3N0qH10ezozCL6HknC5HEqRKn4uJDKvC5uPAXi5kIFovLy1k9FTRTH9LLkw/ph5QW5lmc6i+s9AdXhlWZDy6cibRKkpkwM3N/GAXoc4fBlVzG6Tbpb8d3Zb/ExKNygx8g9vj7rlRZhNffLpOAvjQ4G9NJTQJTdSf+wHD82awr1fZWpbpcsYWssFIX2Y06z5KsWInROpHhzciSNlB+/04lKtQqWgldVOpD+jBpcF/HuhnrLEusyvcYjg0XzXpZ+ltWlerX7C4Fx6ZKQx1n6VjtgGUiLDbIApGAexi+V6U2DB67wUx8hoZEFTIN1Qq2mTmbIVwzcS3TKFH2UTBKkptk2/f3uWI8Dz1Ihdw+Dom2RY4NDjtDn5FVPIK1GFttLSYaFPM4JbJ5eJMOcWSVblne4sGwPFyQIb77juzhaQC/tPuIN2JMYCYuFmKycC6IeCmenwpjtkglWtq1D0+ZQmLrO6nNtMtizzW+VSU5p3HX2lStMNdaYVXsVH2Mm7go9TnNnLQcO5lULI9Zva3S/+GZ8cRhyhcNA1vYd+yXL7u0wKX5pHshnlsGY9zO6oA4lgccrow43WSkIZFlGW/uxwbwxOEoskzTDojTMw9//WXsQ+QwS0t4qgcDjdtFtWg+01l3PqzWcXi1Vp9iVVwRfZzDv3MffwH+lpMDftZ5MAdDvkk3FKk4nPd0ZjXy2rC8yttkxSsZXo8bl9cdh6ozhnceF2Gixp8PkMKzFNLEeX14f9ARWE0zoXtIZRRXCMnlwXw35xQqciPkYeIV6jbbqbfpof4I8VrHe4R0Uuekdmnt8Y2PNw7bnmjHZffkM7sLyqT3ZuhfOmD2Ac8FRDbDZYe85LljIpvhyw75mOe+J7IZ/uCSX7wQ5zIJqwThB79Rm00cxpTTRLYRb8bGojS+u45RIfS1ss4nC9WREjdHb6pm6bVkSbvCLqdiDAxz4JzA/e95AvDnAEkTgDqlPcwJ6RQbc3BK2jksQSJ85mARPLEnmXufRZBMo4NG+2NXBFkH6khEwBwsgif2JHMfsAiSaXTQaO/GbkQiaIF0sUWELSLc0g3jiHYdBTwNudLvmv33rLiVSfxJsVF3sF1WiHGEkIsQchFMpDNxo1QuVFGAREEdl5oSayuH6t1vFCzlx0JjMaDh6zmpndLXc8I1JWmOcsociXh2eioW4kz44gWeVmLhZqDyv6qgHPR7dauKOJSJZ6asb5OiU1HWT0HnaVk/1RXcej+nFc49AulU6KAT9lzMZfmnzWzaZ4BVGqkNurfoIHq1//YGXM0CVCus+AkbMqMfhX+4IuivCJoVAa046ZzPr2qL3KHoFLg5QtpCwS9yHAAAzUyHh7kky3KUxjQTyLkV7bQUd7G+jtOOuIXn+RQ0kINNeWZZoT5WcYFiFDiLoXCtqErFkXPSVHxd8ONnYzYC8j5tbcIDGFecwmwjkj4iNsvFewTXpGNztguvESPa4+hk0MrWdBuZlMrheHDqkdJVkQ6JXomBasMZZCVc/F2G+nMmXPTDPDUfThDHeCYujHNdwqUvUJpBuST7k4UL9JCtoR8XRytJL4tdsTBI8JulwytX3Ck79mlbn7Z/MmGESO2ehDVgTQ0mfRVnJoBqFuSHM5wzXHEEzaOPlURl0nE4mgj2t5ce4vrY68sxJzIetb48onQD7jGnigDluuaFnOXa63RwFKeRzYJ1lpmLY5N4KNOc9Dc7uFeDgqKI9Aekn8X5jn7hApF9IBtOsRzFZ24ehDDYZ+VMzSM3A24oYxttdWvigKoFuiYiG3NQzXrAfLJ0cGDpMSffDUrMC2ib9YnzhtjvE4Y6qf+bjkHuTSWed0vjem+q69zQ5N6hhUzjKs1Vco8vsv7aZZL3YLKF2ZXL00tTjrH23pXLNNNRMK2W6zLVvXLTHbc1DfG8U/+uI+egVcaGpqRhThAw2h8comzo8nH6uqGvD+mMi84eLnQ4jZs2bt+Trm8ypecrZbxNx7LjHSov4ySji66v5v6iK0XCuWsGKv4rzPwo5u3UnOYWPT2R0s6doNFnpY5z39vP84W3n0zHeeDd0/h+gs0TxT4xxXL1e2Mkgivu4sdQdbXwqQniwdIOgmWjlcozeqE43VZxeY1yqe+USrmmmsI8E7hVwRcOu1Jz56p7U37xQblsalVSv2RUkSfZ2WXLvAbzvMftcoSUkAy5my/X0zXlyamchs0e/kR6Urjf4gootCq1kFsZp/hvTwMBmFVo/Kok6tJNlpu8CKaS+pJGoCRT4HokZJ4X2T6+labzQgvDZvG+0kmi1km6ToukGGXVOlGj7vwKS1ovGipeJnsOlSNTA3oOocgZcCu54oMba7hd90rqOMMry1tyL21OOkt507jXil/4XosrTFbSJSfF1S+xtxRuyeKU1rVWLAqEbJjD3lrkspC3imzKzik0e5axk1GH/q1KShKS69a+FVkWJ667ls0XdN2o8MV/uHB0TJLznYhqq36UJXBZ9CAL32lqsu4HG+/9qlC49cU7daWzK2okhuKbG2Hs/pZeoRrjljHLwJ1QWlMDEnW8ZIkc0Wb8jSQ2MmwXT/kQFiALIi2I0es4jUYsNkxwNvDs5uxokt/bQlheV1dIerMRsQYFZ71W8H1FAq1xkbpm1HjUDHJD5wabWjoyWyMno9C7i0tVExfdnDBH4kKBxQnmC/yfkEXzwJ3ppgVKdKjChuo3/M5M2xdJKiriJ9y/nD6v2YN1GAtiYVX6PRB+C8ICWFh1fg+A3wJo6kCNwZaBfsr/4ksht+jUOfH0sFKcdHn8YFnztIJODuUsD+X0eYIOTyOn5aLKaCFxkbQIXUHMYhA1LHjssRhAjpQBlq6UReCggbu9pjeRQkYRYsSkjVDC4ZGTFFx4SRfJW3JmuuWrsKKwbNYOZKwwo9iQbeaff9OnWX4OMOIVNQNJgmZ+QJPXum9r2FNzfW7NSC7t9vokui1fdIWW9Q8YJtJ5+xCaqhCGkcV9LyDaAzC+2t553Cvrg2Nr3sxrcPDrXxj3iwbs7WrowuICaXZ8ZmEQHrOxJxHhbDMkv78DadCuHUhBC4nw/w1I/wKPRbCY+bPl06YZwEHuT+8GniooSwrhOl4c8PjckERk7RryUHvAPPY+ZnYzxPVV7eNXmSH4ghmGjuNrzRA8YYavsMI/ZYS33CJSUuIcFNMbdsXttSh1tdl44mcU9eu4tEEb61HZLL5J6Uc19LBapBllso1Jb/9g0uqe3s/0SqOv8VO8nX+S24EAf9bGb7/+OiHTVfML1Jxn6U7tHU3J/TZLh3NIEzR1guzMD6quE1pX8TkUv1PJZs7nUtJ1BgfzZQzPHsHw7CkMX+tCXYi/GtuEcqeGgfHPeM3ViF821cP5oWfyz2/E3L0BCHsFQDuAat82BLTnR+JONIGnJyZov3m/Q8eEEDqaHa0LJW+Mzx2tLi4f/gc=)).
4. The [curve canonicalization algorithm](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#canonical) described in Pomax' Bezier Primer.

That all three algorithms disagree suggests a major misunderstanding. What is it, and (more importantly) how might I identify such an issue myself?

I referred to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300271/b%c3%a9zier-curves-loop-and-blinn-style) and [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/loopblinn-cubic-curve-rendering-serpentine-arteffect), as well as the [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2005/01/p1000-loop.pdf) in which Loop & Blinn describe their approach, to no effect.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Kind {
    Serpentine,
    Cusp,
    Loop,
    Quadratic,
    Line,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Vec3 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

impl Vec3 {
    fn from_point(p: Point) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3 {
            x: p.x,
            y: p.y,
            z: 1.0,
        }
    }

    fn dot(&self, other: Vec3) -> f32 {
        self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y + self.z * other.z
    }

    fn cross(&self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.y * other.z - self.z * other.y,
            y: self.z * other.x - self.x * other.z,
            z: self.x * other.y - self.y * other.x,
        }
    }
}

fn is_zero(f: f32) -> bool {
    f.abs() < 0.000001
}

fn approx_eq(a: f32, b: f32) -> bool {
    is_zero((a - b).abs())
}

fn normalize(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> (f32, f32, f32) {
    let len = (a * a + b * b + c * c).sqrt();
    if is_zero(len) {
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    } else {
        (a / len, b / len, c / len)
    }
}

pub fn classify(curve: &[Point; 4]) {
    let p0 = Vec3::from_point(curve[0]);
    let p1 = Vec3::from_point(curve[1]);
    let p2 = Vec3::from_point(curve[2]);
    let p3 = Vec3::from_point(curve[3]);

    let loop_blinn = {
        let det1 = -p3.dot(p2.cross(p0));
        let det2 = p3.dot(p2.cross(p0));
        let det3 = -p2.dot(p1.cross(p0));

        let (det1, det2, det3) = normalize(det1, det2, det3);

        let discr = det2 * det2 * (3.0 * det2 * det2 - 4.0 * det3 * det1);

        if is_zero(det1) {
            if !is_zero(det2) {
                Kind::Cusp
            } else if is_zero(det3) {
                Kind::Line
            } else {
                Kind::Quadratic
            }
        } else if is_zero(discr) {
            Kind::Cusp
        } else if discr > 0.0 {
            Kind::Serpentine
        } else {
            Kind::Loop
        }
    };

    let gpu_gems = {
        let a1 = p0.dot(p3.cross(p2));
        let a2 = p1.dot(p0.cross(p3));
        let a3 = p2.dot(p1.cross(p0));
        let d1 = a1 - 2.0 * a2 + 3.0 * a3;
        let d2 = -a2 + 3.0 * a3;
        let d3 = 3.0 * a3;
        let discr = d2 * d2 * (3.0 * d2 * d2 - 4.0 * d1 * d3);

        if is_zero(d1) {
            if is_zero(d2) && is_zero(d3) {
                Kind::Line
            } else {
                Kind::Quadratic
            }
        } else if is_zero(discr) {
            Kind::Cusp
        } else if discr < 0.0 {
            Kind::Serpentine
        } else {
            Kind::Loop
        }
    };

    let paper_js = {
        let x1 = p0.x;
        let y1 = p0.y;
        let x2 = p1.x;
        let y2 = p1.y;
        let x3 = p2.x;
        let y3 = p2.y;
        let x4 = p3.x;
        let y4 = p3.y;

        let a1 = x1 * (y4 - y3) + y1 * (x3 - x4) + x4 * y3 - x3 * y4;
        let a2 = x2 * (y1 - y4) + y2 * (x4 - x1) + x1 * y4 - y1 * x4;
        let a3 = x3 * (y2 - y1) + y3 * (x1 - x2) + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1;
        let d3 = 3.0 * a3;
        let d2 = d3 - a2;
        let d1 = d2 - a2 + a1;
        let (d1, d2, d3) = normalize(d1, d2, d3);

        let d = 3.0 * d2 * d2 - 4.0 * d1 * d3;

        if is_zero(d1) {
            if is_zero(d2) {
                if is_zero(d3) {
                    Kind::Line
                } else {
                    Kind::Quadratic
                }
            } else {
                Kind::Serpentine
            }
        } else if is_zero(d) {
            Kind::Cusp
        } else if d > 0.0 {
            Kind::Serpentine
        } else {
            Kind::Loop
        }
    };

    let pomax_primer = {
        let y31 = p3.y / p1.y;
        let y21 = p2.y / p1.y;
        let x32 = (p3.x - p2.x * y31) / (p2.x - p1.x * y21);

        let x = x32;
        let y = y31 + x32 * (1.0 - y21);

        let cusp_line = (-(x * x) + 2.0 * x + 3.0) / 4.0;
        let loop_at_1 = ((3.0 * 4.0 * x - x * x).sqrt() - x) / 2.0;
        let loop_at_0 = (-(x * x) + 3.0 * x) / 3.0;

        if x > 1.0 || y > 1.0 {
            Kind::Serpentine
        } else if (0.0..1.0).contains(&x) {
            if approx_eq(loop_at_1, y) {
                Kind::Loop
            } else if approx_eq(cusp_line, y) {
                Kind::Cusp
            } else if y < cusp_line || y > loop_at_1 {
                Kind::Serpentine
            } else {
                Kind::Loop
            }
        } else if approx_eq(loop_at_0, y) {
            Kind::Loop
        } else if approx_eq(cusp_line, y) {
            Kind::Cusp
        } else if y < cusp_line || y > loop_at_0 {
            Kind::Loop
        } else {
            Kind::Serpentine
        }
    };

    println!("\tMethod 1 (Loop Blinn 2005): {:?}", loop_blinn);
    println!("\tMethod 2 (GPU Gems 3.25):   {:?}", gpu_gems);
    println!("\tMethod 3 (Paper.js):        {:?}", paper_js);
    println!("\tMethod 4 (Pomax Primer):    {:?}", pomax_primer);
}

pub fn main() {
    let point = [
        Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Line");
    classify(&point);

    let line = [
        Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 2.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 3.0, y: 1.0 },
        Point { x: 4.0, y: 1.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Line");
    classify(&line);

    // loop
    let normal_loop = [
        Point { x: 75.0, y: 98.0 },
        Point { x: 195.0, y: 201.0 },
        Point { x: 63.0, y: 198.0 },
        Point { x: 135.0, y: 103.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Loop");
    classify(&normal_loop);

    let end_loop = [
        Point { x: 120.0, y: 331.0 },
        Point { x: 246.0, y: 261.0 },
        Point { x: 187.0, y: 242.0 },
        Point { x: 148.0, y: 314.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Loop");
    classify(&end_loop);

    // cusp
    let cusp = [
        Point { x: 272.0, y: 305.0 },
        Point { x: 93.0, y: 223.0 },
        Point { x: 221.0, y: 223.0 },
        Point { x: 148.0, y: 314.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Cusp");
    classify(&cusp);

    // serpentine
    let serpentine = [
        Point { x: 148.0, y: 314.0 },
        Point { x: 187.0, y: 242.0 },
        Point { x: 246.0, y: 261.0 },
        Point { x: 272.0, y: 305.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Serpentine");
    classify(&serpentine);

    let serpentine2 = [
        Point { x: 110.0, y: 150.0 },
        Point { x: 25.0, y: 190.0 },
        Point { x: 210.0, y: 250.0 },
        Point { x: 210.0, y: 30.0 },
    ];
    println!("Expecting: Kind::Serpentine");
    classify(&serpentine2);
}
```

Comment: THere is no ´Kind::Line´ in pomax_primer. So clearly the code is wrong. Also sigularity should probably be checked separately for classifivation, so expecting (1,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1) to classify as line in all modes is a bit pushing the envelope

Comment: Also your cusp is allmost a cusp but not quite So some of the differences may just simply be numerical accuracy, its allmost a cusp so serpentine is correct. But its close to loop too so its just a numerical stability question

Comment: Pomax's description of the algorithm does not provide a way to distinguish between lines and arcs, so I defaulted to the more general `Kind::Line` instead. As for numerical stability, it does not seem to be the source of the problem. Printing out the discriminant of each of the three implementations of Loop&Blinn reveals significantly different results (on the order of several orders of magnitude). Furthermore, the reason for using these algorithms is to determine the presence of self intersection, so a cusp/serpentine misclassification due to float instability is less of a concern.

Comment: I see a couple of differences between your code and what is on the GPU Gems website.
1. let a3 = p2.dot(p1.cross(p0));  In the article they cross p1 with p1. I do not know if the error is on your end or theirs.
2. let discr = d2 * d2 * (3.0 * d2 * d2 - 4.0 * d1 * d3); In the article its d1 * d1 * (3.0 * d2 * d2....)

Comment: I think you are correct to cross p1 with p0, however your discr is incorrect.
Also the GPU Gem article makes an assumption so the values aren't the same as Loops but they should have same sign